# Execution failed for task ':react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native, printing, bluetooth

so i got a problem, and i got this error already try finding solution in internet still not yet get it, idk what i forgot to put but the error start when i do yarn start

React native version: 0.71.2

[image]

already try to make the jcenter() still did not work, this is the new React Native version.

new mean to this date new